# How to set PHP $_SERVER variable with Docker?

Tags: php, apache, docker, docker-compose

I've created a PHP/Apache/MySQL development environment with Docker and would like to set variable that I can use with `$_SERVER` in PHP.

Usually I will configure something like that in my virtual host

`SetEnv ENV "developement"`

Is there a way to do it with my docker_compose.yml file ? 
I'll try by using `environment: - ENV=developement` in my docker-compose file but it doesn't work.

Here is my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM php:5.6-apache

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y libpng-dev curl libcurl4-openssl-dev

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql gd curl

RUN a2enmod rewrite

RUN service apache2 restart
```

and my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '2'

services:
  webserver:
    build: ./docker/webserver
    image: dev_web
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /pathtodev/www:/var/www/html
    links:
      - db
    environment:
     - ENV=developement

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports: 
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=******
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=db_dev
```

Comment: That `environment` section looks promising.... See docs: https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#substituting-environment-variables-in-compose-files

Comment: yes, that's where i found the information about `environment` but my var doesn't appear in `$_SERVER`

Comment: Should it? See: [`getenv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php)... or $_ENV... Can't recall honestly. Other factors could be variable order...EGPCS?

Comment: Did you add the `SetEnv ENV "developement"` inside the container virtual host config?

Comment: @TarunLalwani I don't use a virtualhost. my page respond with http://localhost and there is only one project.

Comment: @ficuscr I use this container to code with codeigniter framework and they're using `$_SERVER['CI_ENV']` to check if you're in development or production, ... before, i used my virtual host to set the variable and i would like to do the same thing if possible, so i don't have to change the codeigniter framework (but the `$_ENV`does return the value)

Comment: Researched a bit but I don't really know docker. Suppose drop PHP tag, focus on docker side. Specifically first on getting it set someplace. This was a good read: https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/74 Good luck

Comment: What you are trying should work. Are you sure you didn't wrote it in french on one side when it is expected in english the other (`developement !== development`)

Comment: @b.enoit.be yes i'm sure, i see the variable in $_ENV but not in $_SERVER

Comment: @user2993925 - Is there a reason you don't access via `getenv()`, so that it doesn't matter which global array it is in?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Consider the below **Dockerfile**

```
FROM php:5.6-apache

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y libpng-dev curl libcurl4-openssl-dev

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql gd curl

RUN a2enmod rewrite

RUN service apache2 restart

RUN echo 'PassEnv FIRST_NAME' > /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/expose-env.conf 
RUN echo '<?php echo $_SERVER["FIRST_NAME"];' > /var/www/html/first.php && echo '<?php echo $_SERVER["LAST_NAME"];' > /var/www/html/last.php
```

Now run the container using

```
docker run -it -e FIRST_NAME=TARUN -e LAST_NAME=LALWANI -p 80:80 4ba2aa50347b
```

**Testing**

```
$ curl localhost/first.php
TARUN

$ curl localhost/last.php
$
```

As you can see the only `FIRST_NAME` can be accessed, because we exposed the same using `PassEnv` directive in our apache config insider the container

Answer (score -2):

I know this is a old thread, however, another solution could also be that inside your docker compose, you need to remove the "-" in front of ENV and then instead of "=" it needs to be ":".

It will end up looking like this then:

```
version: '2'

services:
  webserver:
    build: ./docker/webserver
    image: dev_web
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /pathtodev/www:/var/www/html
    links:
      - db
    environment:
      ENV: developement

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports: 
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=******
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=db_dev
```

At least it's working like that in version 3.

Comment: Both formats (of representing an array of values for environment) are supported; they behave identically; this can be verified using `docker-compose config` in same folder as docker-compose.config file; the result will show the entries using a consistent format (and with all variables resolved to their final values).